# ERROR: ConfigurationError: URI scheme 'http' is not supported

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, cypher

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2eBd.png)

tried to connect the Neo4j browser to jupyter with the commaned :

data_base_connection = GraphDatabase.driver(uri = "http://localhost:7474/browser?dbms=neo4j://ellahn3@localhost:7687&db=Graph_ex", auth=("neo4j", "ellahn054"))

out put:

ConfigurationError: URI scheme 'http' is not supported. Supported URI schemes are ['bolt', 'bolt+ssc', 'bolt+s', 'neo4j', 'neo4j+ssc', 'neo4j+s']. Examples: bolt://host[:port] or neo4j://host[:port][?routing_context]

what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use below code for your database connection since you are connecting to the neo4j using a driver and not thru the browser (via http).

```
uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "ellahn054"))
```

Reference: https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/